How to reach optimal speeds with rsync?
I am using rsync to sync around ~2TB of data to a mechanical HDD-5400RPM. It's taking way too long.
How can I improve the sync and check speeds to get as close as possible to maximum/optimal?
Here is the rsync sync command I am running with the flags:
rsync -vvv \ # -v: Basic information, like the files being transferred. # -vv: More details, such as when files are being skipped. # -vvv: Even more detailed, including internal operations and potentially overwhelming.
  -z \ # Compress data during transfer
  -h \ # Human-readable
  -a \ # Archive mode
  -A \ # Preserve ACLs
  -H \ # Preserve hard links
  -S \ # Handle sparse files efficiently
  -X \ # Preserve extended attributes
  "$SRC" \
  "$DEST_DIR" \
  --log-file=$log_file \
  --progress \
  --links \
  --checksum \
  --bwlimit="192M" \
  --delete-during \
  --delete \
  --timeout="60" \
  --compress \
  --no-o \
  --no-g \
  --whole-file \
  --preallocate \
  --atimes \
  --update \
  --partial


And here is the rsync check command I am running with the flags:
rsync -vvv \ # -v: Basic information, like the files being transferred. # -vv: More details, such as when files are being skipped. # -vvv: Even more detailed, including internal operations and potentially overwhelming.
  -z \ # Compress data during transfer
  -h \ # Human-readable
  -a \ # Archive mode
  -A \ # Preserve ACLs
  -H \ # Preserve hard links
  -S \ # Handle sparse files efficiently
  -X \ # Preserve extended attributes
  "$src" \
  "$dest" \
  --log-file=$log_file
  --progress \
  --links \
  --checksum \
  --bwlimit="192M" \
  --compress
  --no-o \
  --no-g \
  --contimeout="60" \
  --ignore-errors \
  --stats \
  --max-delete=0 \
  --whole-file \
  --preallocate \
  --atimes \
  --update

Rsync version:
rsync --version
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2022 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, symlinks, symtimes, hardlinks, hardlink-specials,
    hardlink-symlinks, IPv6, atimes, batchfiles, inplace, append, ACLs,
    xattrs, optional secluded-args, iconv, prealloc, stop-at, no crtimes
Optimizations:
    SIMD-roll, no asm-roll, openssl-crypto, no asm-MD5
Checksum list:
    xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4 sha1 none
Compress list:
    zstd lz4 zlibx zlib none
Daemon auth list:
    sha512 sha256 sha1 md5 md4

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.

Ubuntu Server version:
ubuntu 24.04 (64 bit) LTS


Don't compress when the media between the read and write is not slow.  It sounds like you're using rsync to copy from one disk to another on the same server, so the "media" in between would be a simple pipeline and not slow.  Some of your slowness may be coming from compression causing a cpu bottleneck, so removing the compress flags may give you an increase in throughput.  (I think it will give you better throughput, but I can't say how much.  Maybe a lot, maybe only a little)

Is this over a network or local? Also I notice - other than 5400rpm HDDs being pretty slow - you have a bandwidth limit set up

@SottoVoce, thank you very much for your time, means a lot!
Yes, the source is an SMB mount, and the dest is just a normal HDD connected via SATA (SAS controller in this case).
What you are saying makes sense!
I will remove the compression.
I guess your suggestion about removing the compression is still valid even if the source is an SMB which is locally mounted right?

@JourneymanGeek, thank you very much for your reply!
The source is an SMB mount, and the dest is just a normal HDD connected via SATA (SAS controller in this case).
I will remove the --bwlimit, your suggestion makes sense.
I guess in this case the flag takes no effect when they are locally mounted?
Also as far as I can tell it does not get anywhere near that limit, as far as I can tell it get to around about 64MB if I am not mistaking.

@atkuzmanov yes.  The rsync process is reading $SRC as a filesystem, and rsync's --compress flag does not affect the data read from filesystems (or written to them), it only affects the data transmitted from the sending rsync process to the receiving rsync process.

@atkuzmanov could you add a speed estimate for writing to your HDD to your question? If in doubt, I usually test using yes | pv -S -s "32G" > /target/tmpfilename . 32G here is twice the RAM size of the machine to make sure we're not just writing to in-RAM write buffers.

Notice that modern cpus can saturate a gigabit connection over ssh because of hardware support.  Not so with gzip invoked with -z

can you supply details on the network share conditions? SMB version? any permissions?, are you in the same network of the server or maybe there are several routers/firewalls on the way?

@MarcusMüller, thank you very much for your help! I will try out your method for measuring the speed and report back as soon as I can.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, thank you for your reply! So, you are saying I should use -z? The source and destination are locally mounted.
he source system is a locally mounted TrueNas Scale SMB share. And the destination file system is a local ExFAT SSD attached via SATA via a SAS Controller.

@ram0nvaldez, thank you for your reply. I will check those details and report back as soon as possible. Permissions should be fine as everything seems to be accessible. The source is a TrueNas Scale VM and the destination is on a Ubuntu Server VM both running on the same Proxmox instance on the same server, so no routers firewalls that are in the way that I am aware of, but I am a newbie at most of this, so I could be wrong...

No. You should not use -z

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, got it!

@MarcusMüller,  update with more info, from the command you suggested (the VM has 8GB of RAM):
sudo yes | pv -S -s "16G" > /home/xxx/temp/tempfilename1
16.0GiB 0:00:15 [1.04GiB/s] [==========================================================================================================>] 100%

is /home/xxx the disk you want to sync to?

@MarcusMüller, apologies, my mistake, that was the local disk, here is the correct test and result:
sudo yes | pv -S -s "32G" > /mnt/sd25-4tb-bkp4-mnt4/temp/tempfilename1
32.0GiB 0:01:37 [ 334MiB/s] [==========================================================================================================>] 100%

If this is between local drives? I'd almost suggest using cp, then using rsync to ensure there's no errors.
Other than that, breaking it down
You don't need all these flags
I'm not going to go through each one and tell you why they're a bad idea, but there's a few that stand out
  --bwlimit="192M" \ Sets a bandwidth limit of 192M - considering even a 'old' slow hard drive can beat this handily, this is probably the first thing that's hamstringing you.
If its a SMB mount, its over the network, compression can make sense to save bandwidth, and potentially improve speed but not everything is equally compressible, and on modern machines, its probably worth weighing/testing it out with and without it.
--whole-file, -W         copy files whole (w/o delta-xfer algorithm)
This means you're transferring the whole file, not just what's changed
Then you're running
--partial                keep partially transferred files
This makes no sense since you're downloading the whole lot each time anyway. I'd remove both - let rsync do its magic if a transfer fails or a file changes. Else you might as well just cp , If you're using rsync to keep things synced or to pick up on a failed transfer, whole file makes no sense. Delta transfers are awesome
I also suspect running only one of --delete or --delete-during would be useful - as opposed to both.
I also notice you're telling it to preserve attributes -a which includes preserving the owner and group, then running -no-o and -no-g. Not sure which'll win out but since -a is rlptgoD, picking whichever flags you need makes sense over picking -a then removing some attribute sync options.
At this point, after pointing out the most obvious things - I'd suggest paring down your rsync command to a minimum - referring to the man page, and adding only what you need, based off the answer or the commands.

nope, the compression of an SMB mount doesn't happen over the network; essentially, for the rsync process, the source file is local. It gets requested from the server via SMB by the kernel, not via the rsync protocol by rsync. So, compression here never helps.

Compression is only relevant if bandwidth between the two rsync instances is much less than disk speed.

Thank you very much for your detailed reply! The source system is a locally mounted TrueNas Scale SMB share. And the destination file system is a local ExFAT HDD attached via SATA via a SAS Controller.
It did not see any speeds coming close to the bwlimit, I currently set it to try and throttle an SSD which is also attached as a destination for some files, but I will remove it.
--whole-file - I have a mixture of lots of small and some big files, thought I should add both flags for both types of files...

@atkuzmanov all these options do more harm than good. How about you stop trying to prematurely optimize? In your other question you figured out that exFAT is not a viable file system for what you're doing, so use a different file system, use the absolute standard options for rsync, and then compare. Obviously, the people that wrote rsync are not totally clueless about how to make rsync run performant, so that default options are usually good.

@MarcusMüller, what you are saying here and in the other topic makes sense,  I will do some research on which file system to choose, ext4, XFS, or somethig... and I will give it a try as soon as I get some time to migrate, then I will give it a try with the default options. I will report back how it went. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it!  ( :

Usually -a suffices for copying

considering even a 'old' slow hard drive can beat this handily Not really. Not in general and particularly not when being used by rsync.  Having a short burst of speed because data is in the disk's cache doesn't help large operations.  A 5400-rpm hard drive can do about 50 IO operations per second, and all the lookups rsync does to read directories and file metadata eat into that, potentially lowering the effective bandwidth down into a handful of KB per second.  And even under pure streaming uses, a 5400-rpm drive is going to be lucky to hit 100 MB/sec.
